# How to create UltiDev Web Server Setup written a web applictaion on asp.net 4.0

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, .net-2.0, asp.net-4.0, ultidev-cassini

I have created a web site on asp.net 4.0 and when I create a set up of this site using UltiDev Web Server the set has been completed successfully and installed and when i run it through shortcut the page show this error

> **Server Error in '/WebApp' Application.**
>
> Configuration Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.
>
> Source Error:
>
> ```
>  Line 14: 
>  Line 15:   <system.web>
>  Line 16:     <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
>  Line 17: 
>  Line 18:     <authentication mode="Forms">
> ```
>
> Source File: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\TestSetup\WebApp\web.config    Line: 16
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5466; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5459

and when i create any app on .net framework 2.0 it work fine ..
I had been creating setup for a long time in .net 2.0

Answer (score 1):

Saad,

When registering a web application with UWS, please be sure to use [/CLR:4 parameter](http://ultidev.com/Forums/yaf_postsm2804_Creating-installers-incorporating-UWS-as-a-redistributable-component.aspx#post2804) to ensure your application is going to be loaded into UWS application host process running .NET Framework 4.x.

Comment: Thanks Dear, but when I write /CLR:4 in the Arguments it shows another error and doesn't install properly.
respectively I try to build setup 2.0 it works successful..